# How to make a search api in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a search api using nodejs and MongoDB. I tried to google about this and I did find something there but while trying to implement I get an error saying. I don't know how to fix this honestly I don't know anything about making search API. So any help or suggestion will be helpful for me.

This is the link of the post I found on google [Building a simple search api](https://jonathanmh.com/building-a-simple-searchable-api-with-express-backend/).

> error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"search\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Post\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"search\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "search",
        "path": "_id"
    }
}
```

> This is my code

```
postController.search = (req, res) => {
    var response = [];
    if(typeof req.query.title !== 'undefined'){
        db.Post.filter(function(post) {
            if(post.title === req.query.title){
                console.log(req.body);
                response.push(post);
                console.log(post);
            }
        });
    }
    response = _.uniqBy(response, '_id');
    if(Object.key(req.query).length === 0){
        response = db.Post
    }
    res.json(response);
};
```

> data in the collection

```
"data": [
    {
        "isDeleted": false,
        "_comments": [],
        "_id": "5d39122036117d2ea81b434c",
        "title": "facebook  post",
        "link": "facebook.com",
        "_creator": {
            "createdAt": "2019-07-25T01:42:21.252Z",
            "username": "adityakmr"
        },
        "createdAt": "2019-07-25T02:21:20.634Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

Comment: Please share your one sample collection data.

Comment: Look like this(https://jonathanmh.com/building-a-simple-searchable-api-with-express-backend/) provide search on JSON not for mongo.

Comment: you can directly apply query on Mongo for search

Comment: I have added sample data to my question have a look.

Comment: yes post uses JSON data I though same way can be used for MongoDB as well that's why I tried and I could not find any other tutorial.

Comment: There are so many ways to search on MongoDB collection. example: using regex in find query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an API to search mongoDB collection based on title i.e; a text field try implementing text search feature of mongoDB : [text search in mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html)
, Just create a text index on title field & then create an API with post method which takes in parameter that can be queried against title field.

Text search can be a bit tricky it can help you for **fuzzy/partial/full text** searches - use of regex is also much beneficial.

Checkout links for node.js API example :

[MongoDB NodeJs Docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/tutorials/text-search/)

[Full Text Search with MongoDB & Node.js](https://www.compose.com/articles/full-text-search-with-mongodb-and-node-js/)

[Text Searching with MongoDB](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/text-searching-with-mongodb)

Comment: `db.Post.find({'$text': {'$search': req.body.query}})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json({
                result
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
    })`

Comment: This is how I tried to implement it but it gives null every time.

Comment: Did you create a text index on title & create a mongoDB connection & trying to query collection correctly? also res.send(result) in case of result else in case of error res.status(500).send({err}) should work. what did you get in console.log(result), is that NULL ?

Comment: actually, I am not getting create text index part do I need to put that in my Post model?

Comment: either way you can actually put it there in model/schema file, that way each time code gets triggered it first creates an index on collection and then queries that way you no need to maintain indexes on higher env.'s but my suggestion is to create index directly on Dev DB & have a one time config task to migrate across all env.'s

Comment: @adityakumar : still having issues ?

Comment: I am still not getting this create Index part I put in the model still it gives null. maybe I am doing something wrong or I really have no idea about this thing.

Comment: Can you give me your db connection method and api code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196997/discussion-between-srinivas-y-and-aditya-kumar).

Comment: @adityakumar : Sorry I missed your conversation, Do you still need help !!

Comment: can you show me an example of doing so, please. it would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you specified above, they are using array of objects stored in file called `store.js`, but not mongoDB. So directly they are filtering using `Array.filter` method.

But in mongoDB using mongoose(object modeling tool) you can make use of `collection.find()` method.

So solution to your problem is as follows

```
postController.search = async (req, res) => {
    var response = [];
    if (req.query.title) {
         response = await db.Post.find({title: req.query.title});
    }
    res.json(response);
 };
```

find is inbuilt query method which helps in querying the collections, you can pass multiple properties for querying.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use `async/await` for modularize your code. I suggest don't write your whole code in your `controller.js` file, API can be made by following the way (routes - controller - utils ).

**postRoutes.js**

```
 postRouter.get('/search-post', postCtr.searchPost);
```

**postController.js**

```
const postUtils = require('./postUtils');

const postController = {};

postController.searchPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title } = req.query;
    const result = await postUtils.searchPost(title);
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(err.code).json({ error: err.error });
  }
};

module.exports = postController;
```

**postUtils.js**

```
const Post = require('./postModel');

const postUtils = {};

postUtils.searchPost = async (title) => {
  try {
    let result = [];
    if(title){
      // Even you can perform regex in your search 
      result = await Post.find({ title: title });
    }
     return result;
  } catch (err) {
    const errorObj = { code: 500, error: 'Internal server error' }; // It can be dynamic
    throw errorObj;
  }
};

module.exports = postUtils;
```

**postModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    required: true,
  },
  // Your fields ...
}, { collection: 'post', timestamps: true });

const post = mongoose.model('post', postSchema);

module.exports = post;
```

Using this structure you can easily debug your code and It's also manageable.

Comment: No it's not working. I did as you suggested.It gives me error though.`{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "error": "Internal server error"
    }
}`

Comment: Please check what data are coming from the request, in this case we have make a simple find query but you can add more thing like `$match`  `$sort` etc.. First of all run your application in debug mode and put a debug in the catch of `postUtils.searchPost()` and check what's wrong happened and correct it.